# Tevilas Ezra on Shabbos

Tags: tefilla, shabbat, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, mikvah-ritual-bath, derabanan

Does any source speak about טבילת עזרא specifically in the context of שבת?

I am asking because relations on שבת is indicated to be a preferred/ideal time (based on certain sources (e.g. בבא קמא פב ע"א, כתובות סב ע"ב), while bathing on שבת is potentially problematic (e.g. שולחן ערוך אורח חיים שכו).

Comment: I haven't watched, but from the title I think this video deals with it: https://shasilluminated.org/watch/55657, sorry I can't be more helpful at the moment. I would be very surprised and interested if there were any sources that indicate it is better to not have relations on Shabbat because of tumat keri, or because of the issues surrounding mikva on shabbat. Feel free to let me know what you find out!

Comment: The gemara never gives any indication that bathing on shabbat is problematic (it assumes you can even dunk on yom kippur). Seemingly the chumras you allude to postdate the abolition of ezra's ablution.

Comment: Rav Elyashiv has a teshuva on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

The משנה ברורה speaks about this in [326:24](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.326.24?lang=bi)

> וכתבו האחרונים דמ"מ נראה דמותר לטבול לקריו כיון דנתבטל התקנה ומותר בתורה ובתפלה אפילו קודם טבילה וכנ"ל בסי' פ"ח א"כ לא מחזי כמתקן ע"י הטבילה ועיין במש"כ בביאור הלכה דיש מחמירין וסוברין דאין לחלק בין טבילת קרי לשאר טומאות ומי שנוהג להקל אין למחות בידו כי רוב האחרונים סותמין להקל בזה ועכ"פ בנטמא בשבת ויו"ט גופא נראה בודאי דאין להחמיר וכן נתפשט המנהג להתיר אך יזהר מאד שלא יבוא לידי סחיטה דהוא איסור גמור:

Loosely translated - that precisely because the takana of tevilas Ezra was canceled do some achronim hold that tevilas Ezra is allowed on Shabbos. The Mishna Berura himself is is machmir if one didn't become Tamei on Shabbos itself, but if one became Tamei on Shabbos, then he does not see the need to be machmir and , as the mishna berura explains, the common minhag is to be toivel.